# maximum height of an div tag using javascript in internet explorer 6.0

Tags: css

how can I set de maximum height of an dynamic div tag created using javascript, in internet explorer 6
I tried with this

Element.style.maxHeight="200px"

but it is not working in internet explorer 6.0, it works just fin in Google Chrome or M Firefox

Any idea?
Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE6 does [not have support for max-height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute. You can use javascript expressions such as:

```
height:expression(this.scrollHeight>199?"200px":"auto");
```

to get the same effect. Please note the client needs to have javascript enabled for it to work though.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/fQpYj/

Answer (score 2):

IE6 doesn't support `max-height` or `max-width` (or their `min` equivalents).

It does have its own `expression` support with which you can achieve much the same thing, here's [an article on that](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/01/16/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/). You'll have to detect that you're dealing with IE, but that's fairly easily done with [conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment).